# Save money with price rounding

Tags: code-golf, number

In Canada, the penny is no longer circulated.  Cash payments are rounded to the nearest 5 cents.

Money can be saved by splitting purchases.  For example, two $1.02 items cost $2.04 which rounds up to $2.05, but when buying the items in separate purchases, each price rounds to $1.00 for a total of $2.00.  However, when buying two items at $1.03 each, it is better to buy them in a single purchase.

Another way to save money is using a credit card when rounding is unfavourable, because credit payments are not rounded.  If we want two $1.04 items, the total price will round up to $2.10 regardless of how we split the purchases.  Therefore, we should pay for these items with a credit card.

Write a function or program which accepts a list of prices of items as integers in cents and outputs the lowest possible total price (in cents) for those items which can be achieved through a sequence of purchases, each either by cash or by credit.

Shortest code wins.

### Test cases

```
[] : 0
[48] : 48
[92, 20] : 110
[47, 56, 45] : 145
[55, 6, 98, 69] : 225
[6, 39, 85, 84, 7] : 218
[95, 14, 28, 49, 41, 39] : 263
[92, 6, 28, 30, 39, 93, 53] : 335
[83, 33, 62, 12, 34, 29, 18, 12] : 273
[23, 46, 54, 69, 64, 73, 58, 92, 26] : 495
[19, 56, 84, 23, 20, 53, 96, 92, 91, 58] : 583
[3, 3, 19, 56, 3, 84, 3, 23, 20, 53, 96, 92, 91, 58, 3, 3] : 598
[2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] : 19
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Ruby, <strike>119</strike> 105 characters (93 body)

```
def f s
a,b,c,d=(1..4).map{|i|s.count{|x|x%5==i}}
s.reduce(0,:+)-a-(c-m=c>d ?d:c)/2-2*(b+m+(d-m)/3)
end
```

Two characters may be saved if the algorithm is allowed to crash when fed an empty shopping list.

Comment: You may change to `s.reduce(:+)` (normally you even don't need parantheses, but in your case...) and inline `m` for additional 2 chars.

Comment: And of course `a,b,c,d=(1..4).map{|i|s.count{|x|x%5==i}}`.

Comment: @Howard if I remove `0,` from the `reduce` call, the code breaks for the empty input. I did mention that in the answer. Inlining m doesn't seem to help. Thanks for the last suggestion - that was stupid from me.

Comment: You can write `(c-m=c>d ?d:c)` which gives you two chars.

Comment: @Howard I thought that would break because `-` has higher priority than `=`. Is it that the assignment has a high priority on its left side (as in, to ensure the left operand is an lvalue)?

Comment: I didn't think about that before - and actually I can't find anything in the lang spec about this situation. Anyway, it works ;-) and is interesting.

Comment: @cardboard_box tested with all supplied test cases and works

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (54 chars)

```
~]4,{){\5%=}+1$\,,}%~.2$>$:m- 3/m+@+2*@@m- 2/++~)+{+}*
```

This is a program which takes input from stdin as space-separated values. One character could be saved by forcing the input format to instead be as GolfScript arrays.

[Test cases online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=O1sKJycgIyAwCic0OCcgIyA0OAonOTIgMjAnICMgMTEwCic0NyA1NiA0NScgIyAxNDUKJzU1IDYgOTggNjknICMgMjI1Cic2IDM5IDg1IDg0IDcnICMgMjE4Cic5NSAxNCAyOCA0OSA0MSAzOScgIyAyNjMKJzkyIDYgMjggMzAgMzkgOTMgNTMnICMgMzM1Cic4MyAzMyA2MiAxMiAzNCAyOSAxOCAxMicgIyAyNzMKJzIzIDQ2IDU0IDY5IDY0IDczIDU4IDkyIDI2JyAjIDQ5NQonMTkgNTYgODQgMjMgMjAgNTMgOTYgOTIgOTEgNTgnICMgNTgzCiczIDMgMTkgNTYgMyA4NCAzIDIzIDIwIDUzIDk2IDkyIDkxIDU4IDMgMycgIyA1OTgKJzIgMyA0IDQgNCA0IDQnICMgMTkKXXsKCn5dNCx7KXtcNSU9fSsxJFwsLH0lfi4yJD4kOm0tIDMvbStAKzIqQEBtLSAyLysrfikreyt9KgoKcH0v)

The most interesting trick is `.2$>$` for a  non-destructive `min` operator.

---

My analysis of the maths is essentially the same as Jan's and Ray's: considering values mod 5, the only saving is on transactions worth 1 or 2. The credit card option means that we never round up. So an item which costs 5n+2 cents can't benefit from bundling; nor can an item worth 5n+1 cents (because combining two 1-cent savings into a 2-cent saving doesn't give any benefit). 0 is the additive identity, so the only interesting cases involve values of 3 and 4. `3+3 = 1` and `3+4 = 4+4+4 = 2`; if we have mixed 3s and 4s then we optimise by preferring `3+4` over `3+3` (strictly better) or `4+4+4` (equivalent).

Comment: +1 - although those spaces look so lavishly ;-) You might remove them by saving -m (`~):m`) unfortunately with no reduction in char count.

Comment: @Howard, I know, I tried it too. :D

Answer (score 3):

**C++: 126 character**

```
int P(int*m,int i){int t=0,h=0,d;while(i>-1){d=m[i]%5;t+=m[i--];d<3?t-=d:d==4?h++,t-=2:h--;}h<0?t+=h/2:t+=(h-h/3)*2;return t;}
```

Welcome to give guidance to put this program becomes shorter.Here is the test program,compile with tdm-gcc 4.7.1 compiler and run normally.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//m[i]表示单个商品的价格,t表示所有商品总价格,
//d为单个商品价格取模后的值,h为单个商品价格取模后值为3的个数,
//f为单个商品价格取模后值为4的个数
int P(int*m,int i){int t=0,h=0,d;while(i>-1){d=m[i]%5;t+=m[i--];d<3?t-=d:d==4?h++,t-=2:h--;}h<0?t+=h/2:t+=(h-h/3)*2;return t;}

int main() {
int p1[1]={48};
int p2[2]={92,20};
int p3[3]={47,56,45};
int p4[4]={55,6,98,69};
int p5[5]={6,39,85,84,7};
int p6[6]={95,14,28,49,41,39};
int p7[7]={92,6,28,30,39,93,53};
int p8[8]={83,33,62,12,34,29,18,12};
int p9[9]={23,46,54,69,64,73,58,92,26};
int p10[10]={19,56,84,23,20,53,96,92,91,58};
int p11[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
cout<<P(p1,0)<<endl
    <<P(p2,1)<<endl
    <<P(p3,2)<<endl
    <<P(p4,3)<<endl
    <<P(p5,4)<<endl
    <<P(p6,5)<<endl
    <<P(p7,6)<<endl
    <<P(p8,7)<<endl
    <<P(p9,8)<<endl
    <<P(p10,9)<<endl
    <<P(p11,9)<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3 (115 chars)

```
m=eval(input());t=a=b=0
for v in m:d=v%5;t+=v-d*(d<3);a+=d==3;b+=d==4
d=min(a,b);a-=d;b-=d;print(t-d*2-a//2-b//3*2)
```

### Python 2 (106 chars)

```
m=input();t=a=b=0
for v in m:d=v%5;t+=v-d*(d<3);a+=d==3;b+=d==4
d=min(a,b);a-=d;b-=d;print t-d*2-a/2-b/3*2
```

Comment: The question asks for the total price, so there should be one output for the entire list.  For example, the input `[3,4,9]` should give `14`, because you can combine the 3 and 4 cent items to get a 7 cent purchase which you pay in cash with 5 cents, and the remaining 9 cent item you pay with credit because it would otherwise round up.

Comment: Given `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, this gives `0.0, 0.0, 2.5, 3.33, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.5, 8.33, 10.0`, which sums to `46.66`.  However, the correct answer is `45`, so the sum of the numbers you print is not the correct answer, and therefore this solution is incorrect.

Comment: This answer was wroted when job not contain "total" yet

Comment: I'm afraid I have to recommend deletion. Asker didn't change the requirements - he clarified them. If the price for each item separately were desired, then why the mention of a "sequence of purchases / single purchase" and the discussion of which one is favourable?

Comment: I delete wrong answers. Now It's shortest Python answers

Answer (score 1):

### R 143

```
function(x)min(sapply(rapply(partitions::listParts(length(x)),
                             function(i)min(sum(x[i]),5*round(sum(x[i])/5)),h="l"),
                      function(x)sum(unlist(x))))
```

Tests (where `P` is an alias for the code above)

```
> P(c(48))
[1] 48
> P(c(92, 20))
[1] 110
> P(c(47, 56, 45))
[1] 145
> P(c(55, 6, 98, 69))
[1] 225
> P(c(6, 39, 85, 84, 7))
[1] 218
> P(c(95, 14, 28, 49, 41, 39))
[1] 263
> P(c(92, 6, 28, 30, 39, 93, 53))
[1] 335
> P(c(83, 33, 62, 12, 34, 29, 18, 12))
[1] 273
> P(c(23, 46, 54, 69, 64, 73, 58, 92, 26))
[1] 495
> P(c(19, 56, 84, 23, 20, 53, 96, 92, 91, 58))
[1] 583
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <strike>112 126 167</strike> 157

**Edit**: Cases of {3, 3} and {4,4,4} now handled thanks to Peter Taylor and cardboard_box.

```
n_~g~o_ := {a___, Sequence @@ n, b___} :> {a, b, o};
f@s_ := Tr@Join[#[[2]], Sort@#[[1]] //. {1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, g[{3, 4}, 5], g[{3, 3}, 5], 
   g[{4, 4, 4}, 10]}] &[Transpose[{m = Mod[#, 5], # - m} & /@ s]]
```

Note: Non-purchases (test case #1) are entered as `f[{0}]`.

**How it works**

1. For each item, the greatest multiple of 5 less than the respective price will be paid  regardless of form of payment.  (No getting around that.)
2. The remainders of `Mod[n, 5]` are then processed:  1's and 2's become 0's.  Zeros stay unchanged.
3. Each pair {3, 4} -> {5}; afterwards each pair {3, 3} -> {5}; then the triple, {4,4,4}-> {10}, if applicable.
4. The remaining 4's, if any, remain unchanged (paid by credit card).
5. Original multiples of 5 summed with remainders that were tweaked (or not) in steps (2) to (4).

**Testing**

`a12` adjusts for {3,3}
`a13` adjusts for {4,4,4}

```
a1={0};
a2={48};
a3={92,20};
a4={47,56,45};
a5={55,6,98,69} ;
a6={6,39,85,84,7};
a7={95,14,28,49,41,39};
a8={92,6,28,30,39,93,53};
a9={83,33,62,12,34,29,18,12};
a10={23,46,54,69,64,73,58,92,26};
a11={19,56,84,23,20,53,96,92,91,58};
a12={3,3,19,56,3,84,3,23,20,53,96,92,91,58,3,3};
a13={2,3,4,4,4,4,4};

f /@ {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13}
```

> {0, 48, 110, 145, 225, 218, 263, 335, 273, 495, 583, 598, 19}

Comment: What about {3,3}?

Comment: @PeterTaylor.  Good point. It slipped by.

Comment: What about {4,4,4}?  I think with {3,4} -> {5}, {3,3} -> {5} and {4,4,4} -> {10} (in that order) it should give optimal answers.

Comment: @cardboard_box You are right! See update.

Comment: I added your additional test cases to the question.  The ones I had were generated randomly so those corner cases didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

### APL, 58 characters

```
{a b c d←+/(⍳4)∘.=5|⍵⋄(+/⍵)-a-(⌊2÷⍨c-m)-2×b+m+⌊3÷⍨d-m←c⌊d}
```

The program is essentially a direct translation of [Jan Dvorak's Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11784/7911).

---

```
      {a b c d←+/(⍳4)∘.=5|⍵⋄(+/⍵)-a-(⌊2÷⍨c-m)-2×b+m+⌊3÷⍨d-m←c⌊d}⍬
0
      {a b c d←+/(⍳4)∘.=5|⍵⋄(+/⍵)-a-(⌊2÷⍨c-m)-2×b+m+⌊3÷⍨d-m←c⌊d}95 14 28 49 41 39
263
      {a b c d←+/(⍳4)∘.=5|⍵⋄(+/⍵)-a-(⌊2÷⍨c-m)-2×b+m+⌊3÷⍨d-m←c⌊d}19 56 84 23 20 53 96 92 91 58
583
```

`⍬` is the empty vector.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia 83C

```
C=L->let
w,z,x,y=map(i->[i==x%5for x=L]|sum,1:4)
L|sum-(x+2w+3min(x,y)+4z)>>1
end
```

### Explaination:

In one purchase, you can save 2 cent at most. <s>So if you have a combination that can save you 2 cents, just buy it that way and it will be optimial</s>. For example, if you have `x` items with price 3(mod 5) and `y` items with price 4(mod 5), you can make `min(x, y)` number of (3, 4) pairs, which save you `2 min(x, y)` cents. Then you use the rest 3's, if any, to save you `max(0, x-min(x,y)) / 2` cents. This can also be calculated by `(max(x,y)-y)/2`

```
w = sum(1 for p in prices if p % 5 == 1)
z = sum(1 for p in prices if p % 5 == 2)
x = sum(1 for p in prices if p % 5 == 3)
y = sum(1 for p in prices if p % 5 == 4)

ans = sum(prices) - (w + 2 z + 2 min(x, y) + div(max(x, y) - y, 2))
    = sum(prices) - (2w + 4z + 4 min(x, y) + x + y - min(x, y) - y) `div` 2
    = sum(prices) - (2w + 4z + 3 min(x, y) + x) `div` 2
```

### Edit

This solution is wrong.

Comment: +1 for using a relatively unknown language that might be interesting to learn

Comment: It's a new language under active development. It combines many strengh from different languages. Hope that more people can known it.

Comment: The analysis isn't quite complete, because if you have `4 4 4 3 3` then `4 4 4` is a combination which can save 2 cents, but buying it that way isn't optimal. (In fact, you don't seem to be taking `4 4 4` into account at all. Doesn't this code fail the last test case?)